# Resuming Training of Keras Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

I'm using `tensorflow.keras` in order to build a simple neural network with 3 dense layers. I was able to successfully train the model for 9000 epochs reaching a Mean of Squared Errors (`MSE`) of 0.0496. However resuming the model, it starts training at about 57 `MSE`.

This might indicates that the model weights were not loaded successfully but when restarting the training process from the beginning (without loading previous saved weights), `MSE` starts at about +9000.

**Edit:**

1. *So is this a normal issue, or i have something wrong done?*
2. Why accuracy is always 0.0 even after 9000 epochs?

My code below:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import pathlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

print(tf.__version__)

dataset_path = 'D:\\data.csv'
checkpoint_model_json_path = 'modelBackup/model.json'
checkpoint_weights_h5_path = 'modelBackup/weights00009000.h5'
resume_from_checkpoint = True

print('reading dataset...')
column_names = ['paircode','x1o','x1h','x1l','x1c','x1v','x2o','x2h','x2l','x2c','x2v','x3o','x3h','x3l','x3c','x3v','x4o','x4h','x4l','x4c','x4v','x5o','x5h','x5l','x5c','x5v','x6o','x6h','x6l','x6c','x6v','x7o','x7h','x7l','x7c','x7v','x8o','x8h','x8l','x8c','x8v','x9o','x9h','x9l','x9c','x9v','x10o','x10h','x10l','x10c','x10v','x11o','x11h','x11l','x11c','x11v','x12o','x12h','x12l','x12c','x12v','x13o','x13h','x13l','x13c','x13v','x14o','x14h','x14l','x14c','x14v','x15o','x15h','x15l','x15c','x15v','x16o','x16h','x16l','x16c','x16v','x17o','x17h','x17l','x17c','x17v','x18o','x18h','x18l','x18c','x18v','x19o','x19h','x19l','x19c','x19v','x20o','x20h','x20l','x20c','x20v','x21o','x21h','x21l','x21c','x21v','x22o','x22h','x22l','x22c','x22v','x23o','x23h','x23l','x23c','x23v','x24o','x24h','x24l','x24c','x24v','x25o','x25h','x25l','x25c','x25v','x26o','x26h','x26l','x26c','x26v','x27o','x27h','x27l','x27c','x27v','x28o','x28h','x28l','x28c','x28v','x29o','x29h','x29l','x29c','x29v','x30o','x30h','x30l','x30c','x30v','x31o','x31h','x31l','x31c','x31v','x32o','x32h','x32l','x32c','x32v','x33o','x33h','x33l','x33c','x33v','x34o','x34h','x34l','x34c','x34v','x35o','x35h','x35l','x35c','x35v','x36o','x36h','x36l','x36c','x36v','x37o','x37h','x37l','x37c','x37v','x38o','x38h','x38l','x38c','x38v','x39o','x39h','x39l','x39c','x39v','x40o','x40h','x40l','x40c','x40v','x41o','x41h','x41l','x41c','x41v','x42o','x42h','x42l','x42c','x42v','x43o','x43h','x43l','x43c','x43v','x44o','x44h','x44l','x44c','x44v','x45o','x45h','x45l','x45c','x45v','x46o','x46h','x46l','x46c','x46v','x47o','x47h','x47l','x47c','x47v','x48o','x48h','x48l','x48c','x48v','x49o','x49h','x49l','x49c','x49v','x50o','x50h','x50l','x50c','x50v','nextclose']
dataset = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, names=column_names,
                      na_values = "?", comment='\t',
                      sep=",", skipinitialspace=True, skiprows = [0])

print('printing dataset tail...')
print(dataset.tail())

train_dataset = dataset.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=0)
test_dataset = dataset.drop(train_dataset.index)

train_labels = train_dataset.pop('nextclose')
test_labels = test_dataset.pop('nextclose')

def norm(x):
  return x
#  return (x - train_stats['mean']) / train_stats['std']

print('normalizing dataset...')  
normed_train_data = norm(train_dataset)
normed_test_data = norm(test_dataset)

def build_model():
  print('building the model')
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu), layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  return model

def load_model_():
  print('loading the model')
  # load json and create model
  json_file = open(checkpoint_model_json_path, 'r')
  loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
  json_file.close()
  loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
  # load weights into new model
  loaded_model.load_weights(checkpoint_weights_h5_path)
  print("Loaded model from disk")

  return loaded_model


if resume_from_checkpoint:
  model = load_model_()
else:
  model = build_model()

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error', 'accuracy'])
model.summary()

print('testing 10 widthed batch...')
example_batch = normed_train_data[:10]
example_result = model.predict(example_batch)
print(example_result)

def plot_history(history):
  hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
  hist['epoch'] = history.epoch

  plt.figure()
  plt.xlabel('Epoch')
  plt.ylabel('Mean Abs Error [nextclose]')
  plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['mean_absolute_error'],
           label='Train Error')
  plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['val_mean_absolute_error'],
           label = 'Val Error')
  plt.ylim([0,5])
  plt.legend()

  plt.figure()
  plt.xlabel('Epoch')
  plt.ylabel('Mean Square Error [$nextclose^2$]')
  plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['mean_squared_error'],
           label='Train Error')
  plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['val_mean_squared_error'],
           label = 'Val Error')
  plt.ylim([0,20])
  plt.legend()
  plt.show()

print('fitting the model...')
mc = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('weights{epoch:08d}.h5', save_weights_only=True, period=500)

print('saving the model...')
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

history = model.fit(
  normed_train_data, train_labels,
  epochs=1, validation_split = 0.2, verbose=2,
  batch_size=100000, callbacks=[mc])

print('evaluating the model...')
loss, mae, mse, accuracy = model.evaluate(normed_test_data, test_labels, verbose=0)
print("Testing set Mean Abs Error: {:5.2f} nextclose".format(mae))
print("Testing set Accuracy: {:5.2f} nextclose".format(accuracy))
```

Output:

```
1.13.1
reading dataset...
printing dataset tail...
        paircode      x1o      x1h      x1l      x1c  x1v      x2o      x2h      x2l      x2c  x2v      x3o      x3h  ...     x48c  x48v     x49o     x49h     x49l     x49c  x49v     x50o     x50h     x50l     x50c  x50v  nextclose
381045        50  112.606  112.622  112.606  112.619  0.0  112.580  112.581  112.561  112.575  0.0  112.601  112.612  ...  112.118   0.0  112.083  112.090  112.079  112.087   0.0  112.025  112.033  112.023  112.032   0.0    112.033
381046        50  112.580  112.581  112.561  112.575  0.0  112.601  112.612  112.598  112.599  0.0  112.581  112.599  ...  112.087   0.0  112.025  112.033  112.023  112.032   0.0  112.031  112.034  112.031  112.033   0.0    112.141
381047        50  112.601  112.612  112.598  112.599  0.0  112.581  112.599  112.580  112.593  0.0  112.548  112.548  ...  112.032   0.0  112.031  112.034  112.031  112.033   0.0  112.142  112.149  112.140  112.141   0.0    112.157
381048        50  112.581  112.599  112.580  112.593  0.0  112.548  112.548  112.540  112.542  0.0  112.551  112.565  ...  112.033   0.0  112.142  112.149  112.140  112.141   0.0  112.161  112.161  112.157  112.157   0.0    112.121
381049        50  112.548  112.548  112.540  112.542  0.0  112.551  112.565  112.551  112.565  0.0  112.564  112.577  ...  112.141   0.0  112.161  112.161  112.157  112.157   0.0  112.121  112.129  112.121  112.121   0.0    112.140

[5 rows x 252 columns]
normalizing dataset...
loading the model
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py:435: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
2019-04-05 12:10:15.520118: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
Loaded model from disk
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\losses_utils.py:170: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               129024
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               262656
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 256)               131328
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257
=================================================================
Total params: 523,265
Trainable params: 523,265
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
testing 10 widthed batch...
[[106.244064]
 [ 76.667534]
 [ 82.01627 ]
 [ 79.776405]
 [116.600204]
 [ 95.28444 ]
 [ 76.96633 ]
 [118.25993 ]
 [120.39911 ]
 [108.5381  ]]
fitting the model...
saving the model...
Train on 243872 samples, validate on 60968 samples
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
 - 6s - loss: 56.9330 - mean_absolute_error: 5.3921 - mean_squared_error: 56.9330 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 38.9868 - val_mean_absolute_error: 6.1875 - val_mean_squared_error: 38.9868 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
evaluating the model...
Testing set Mean Abs Error:  6.19 nextclose
Testing set Accuracy:  0.00 nextclose
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug fixed currently in `tensorflow-gpu-nighlybuild 2.0` as mentioned [here.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27049)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply build the model, compile it and keep the randomly initialized weights to start training. Next, to resume training : build the model, compile it and then reload the saved weights.

Comment: In my case i'm building the model, loading weights then compiling it, so if you mean that i must compile the model then load the weights, i tried it:  

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu), layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

**But same result**

Answer (score 0):

for resume training you should not run the full code ,
just run this :

```
model= load_model('model.h5')
history = model.fit(normed_train_data, train_labels, epochs=1, v 
    validation_split = 0.2, verbose=2,
    batch_size=128, callbacks=[mc])`
```

However you shoud edit this:

```
mc = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('weights{epoch:08d}.h5', save_weights_only=True, period=100)
```

into this:

```
mc = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('weights{epoch:08d}.h5', save_weights_only=False, period=100)
```

Comment: sorry bu I'm sure that this not enough, you should surely build or load the structure of the model and logically you should also reload the weights into the net.

Comment: you can load weight like this :

Comment: from keras.models import load_model   model =load_model('model.h5')

Comment: THANKS @Amara you where right!!!, i should simply change the `save_weights_only` to `False` in `keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint`. Then i was able to load the model after saving it as simple as calling `load_model('model.h5')` without even building it or loading the `json` file

Comment: Sorry but Why accuracy is always 0.0 even after 9000 epochs? any ideas please?

Comment: you should add activation function in the last layer if regression problem add  'linear' . if classification add softmax or sigmoid and change your loss function